# How do I put the proper data from this array into the place I need it to go?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Here's the idea, pull color hex codes that are supplied from the SQL and injected into the span in these list items and then use those hex codes to set the background color of the span it's in. I was able to get the proper information into the array but I'm not sure how I should go about setting the backgroundColor rule in the correct order with that array.

```
<ul id="color-hr">
        <li id="hr-aqua">
            <a href="Javascript:"><span></span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Javascript:"><span>70859a</span> Jetstream</a></li>
                <li><a href="Javascript:"><span>4d98b5</span> Periwinkle</a></li>
                <li><a href="Javascript:"><span>5ecfcc</span> Deep Caribean</a></li>
                <li><a href="Javascript:"><span>b6d8d5</span> Sky</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>

/** Color Bar **/
$("ul#color-hr > li > ul li a span").each(function (data, i) {
    $this = $(this);
    var colorArr = $this.map(function () { return $this.text() });
    var barColor = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < colorArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(colorArr);
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#' + barColor);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to loop twice.

You can change your code to:

```
$("ul#color-hr > li > ul li a span").each(function (data, i) {
    $this = $(this);

    $this.css('backgroundColor', '#' + $this.text());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the inner loop.

```
$("ul#color-hr > li > ul li a span").each(function (data, i) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#' + $(this).text())
});
```

Also, for reference, you may want to consider the HTML5 "data-" attribute. It's a little redundant in this case, but can come in handy.

```
<li><a href="Javascript:"><span data-bg="#70859a">70859a</span> Jetstream</a></li>
```

...would use:

```
 $(this).css('backgroundColor', $(this).data("bg"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the inner loop, as `each` already loops through them.

```
//for (var i = 0; i < colorArr.length; i++) {
    //console.log(colorArr);
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#' + $this.text());
//}
```

Instead of using `barColor` that was equal to 0, I replaced it with the current iteration's text.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6Hfn/3/